# How to correctly parse a DateTime in this format: "2013-04-29T00:00:00"

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I consume a web service which returns me some dates as string, and I use `DateTime.Parse` to get the correspondente `DateTime` objects. It is working, but I'm afraid my usage of `DateTime.Parse` may be vulnerable to bugs caused by different locale settings. The date returned is in the following format:

```
2014-04-24T00:00:00
```

The code I use to parse it:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(strValue);
```

Is there some way (such as passing a format provider, or using another method) in which I guarantee that my parsing routine will work regardless of the machine locale settings?

Comment: This is ISO8601 date time format that *does not* change depending on machine settings. Passing culture would not hurt, but optional.

Comment: Also be aware that the result of any of these will have a `.Kind` value of `Unspecified` - which may or may not be what you were expecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the shortest form! Your format is ISO 8601-format (http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). It is recognized with any culture!

So your way is the simplest way: `DateTime result = DateTime.Parse("2008-06-15T21:15:07");`

If you are not sure, use: `DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact("2008-06-15T21:15:07", "s", null);`

Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx#properties

Answer (score 5):

If you want to parse a date independent of the user's locale, then use the [invariant culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(strValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Yes, your answer will work, but it will work with any culture.

Comment: @MartinMulder It's not clear what you mean.  This code will behave the same way in the context of any culture: it will parse numbers according to the invariant culture, and ignore the culture rules for the current context.  This appears to be what the OP desires.

Comment: Yes, but this is more than he want. Check out my answer. It does not matter what culture he is using (en-US, nl-NL, Invaruant, etc.). The format he is using is ALWAYS parsed correctly, so you do not have to provider a culture explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an exact format, I'd use a non-ambiguous format string:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2014-04-24T00:00:00", "yyyy\\-MM\\-dd\\THH\\:mm\\:ss", null)
// or to reduce the C#-escaped backslashes:
DateTime.ParseExact("2014-04-24T00:00:00", @"yyyy\-MM\-dd\THH\:mm\:ss", null)
```

The escaped hyphens and colons, as well as the escaped `T`, mean that those are constant values. So this line should work regardless of any other factors.

Comment: A big solution while "s" would have been much shorter!

Comment: If "s" works for you, go for it. However, I feel the clarity of spelling it out is helpful for anyone reading your code or troubleshooting in the future. It removes any ambiguity, and doesn't rely on any built-in standards - it just works, and will never not work, and you'll never need to look at the documentation to find out why it does or doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use the [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

```
string dateString, format;  
DateTime result;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

dateString = "2013-04-29T00:00:00";
format = "s";

result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

Where the "s" format string represents a sortable DateTime (MSDN on [Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx#properties))

Answer (score 0):

```
  string dateString;
  DateTime dateValue;

  // Parse a string.
  dateString = "2014-04-24T00:00:00"; 
  if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "o",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, dateValue, 
             dateValue.Kind);
```

Comment: This will fail because the "o" format requires seven decimal places of  fractional seconds.